# elementtree, edit list of list of elements

Tags: python, xml, list, elementtree

I have a list of lists of elements that are related, a snippet of which is shown below. So `config` and `action` are children of `command`:

```
all1= [[<Element '{http://clish.sourceforge.net/XMLSchema}COMMAND' at 0x7ff2ae48b690>, <Element '{http://clish.sourceforge.net/XMLSchema}PARAM' at 0x7ff2ae48b710>, <Element '{http://clish.sourceforge.net/XMLSchema}ACTION' at 
0x7ff2ae48b750>, <Element '{http://clish.sourceforge.net/XMLSchema}CONFIG' at 
0x7ff2ae48b790>], [<Element '{http://clish.sourceforge.net/XMLSchema}COMMAND' at
0x7ff2ae48b890>, <Element '{http://clish.sourceforge.net/XMLSchema}CONFIG' at 
0x7ff2ae48b8d0>, <Element '{http://clish.sourceforge.net/XMLSchema}ACTION' at 
0x7ff2ae48b950>], [<Element '{http://clish.sourceforge.net/XMLSchema}COMMAND' at 
0x7ff2ae48ba10>, <Element '{http://clish.sourceforge.net/XMLSchema}CONFIG' at 
0x7ff2ae48ba50>, <Element '{http://clish.sourceforge.net/XMLSchema}ACTION' at 
0x7ff2ae48bad0>], [<Element '{http://clish.sourceforge.net/XMLSchema}COMMAND' at 
0x7ff2ae48bb90>, <Element '{http://clish.sourceforge.net/XMLSchema}CONFIG' at 
0x7ff2ae48bbd0>, <Element       '{http://clish.sourceforge.net/XMLSchema}ACTION' at 
0x7ff2ae48bc50>]]
```

This is generated by:

```
commands = root.findall('{http://clish.sourceforge.net/XMLSchema}'
                        'VIEW/{http://clish.sourceforge.net/XMLSchema}COMMAND')   
command_string = ""
all1 = []
for command in commands:
    all1.append(list(command.iter()))
all1 = [x for x in all1 if len(x) > 2]
print all1
```

I wish to change the text of each action element to be the attributes of each config tag.

here is an example of what I mean:

```
<COMMAND name="shutdown"
        help="Shutdown the selected interface">
        <CONFIG priority="0x7F01" />
        <ACTION>
        /klas/klish-scripts/interfaces.py conf -i ${iface} --enable 0
        </ACTION>
    </COMMAND>

    <COMMAND name="no shutdown"
        help="Enable the selected interface">
        <CONFIG operation="unset" pattern="^shutdown"/>
        <ACTION>
        /klas/klish-scripts/interfaces.py conf -i ${iface} --enable 1
        </ACTION>
    </COMMAND>
```

The first config has one attrib so it's action tag text should change to "0x7F01"
In the second config there is "unset" and "shutdown" so that should be the new action text, leaving this as the new xml:

```
<COMMAND name="shutdown"
        help="Shutdown the selected interface">
        <CONFIG priority="0x7F01" />
        <ACTION>
        0x7F01
        </ACTION>
    </COMMAND>

    <COMMAND name="no shutdown"
        help="Enable the selected interface">
        <CONFIG operation="unset" pattern="^shutdown"/>
        <ACTION>
        unset ^shutdown
        </ACTION>
    </COMMAND>
```

So I should be setting each attrib to a variable and passing it to the action.text?

Would this have been easier if I had done these operations before creating the list? By manipulating the elements and then adding them? The I have references to tag, text etc already. Or can I still do this with a list of elements?